# Sample real-word ASP.NET MVC 3 production applications code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone share links of **production code** to real-word ASP.NET MVC applications. It's interesting to see on **production code** and implementation staff!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the best one for me its [Kigg starter kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/kigg).

Answer (score 2):

..And of course the almighty [NerdDinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/) (which is not really real website, but rather an Implementation of the [well known tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm)).

Comment: NerdDinner is very much a real website!

Answer (score 1):

This one: http://getrocketship.com/ It's a CMS service for small businesses.

And... http://www.lizzabethbrown.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Umbarco CMS](http://umbraco.com/) is an example of an [open source](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) ASP.NET MVC built CMS. While the [Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples/mvc-music-store) is not a real world application it is close enough and a good from learning perspective.

Answer (score 1):

What about http://www.stackoverflow.com? :)

Comment: I think you might not be able to understand question.

Comment: Well, you originally asked for Production MVC sites, so I don't think I misunderstood anything since Stackoverflow.com is built on MVC3. Don't think the vote-down is justified... Don't forget that people can see what the question read *before* you edited it..

Comment: Yngve, Initially, i am mean production code of MVC builed sites.